# Dispersion of Carbon Monoxide

Tags: fluid-mechanics

This question stems from a debate between a few engineers at work recently.

Imagine we have a trench or an enclosed box with no ceiling and impermeable walls with the dimensions of 20 × 10 × 20 (l × w × h). If someone were to start a gas powered machine in the bottom of the box, how would the carbon monoxide disperse within the box?

**Two scenarios were imagined:**

1. The carbon monoxide disperses within the box, mixing with the air inside of it. The concentration continuously increases until the machine is turned off. However, concentrations will remain elevated since there is no air flow in the box to force air out.
2. Because there is no ceiling and since the exhaust coming from the engine is hot and carbon monoxide is lighter then the components of air, the carbon monoxide will rise and exit the box and concentrations will drop after the machine is turned off.

**My questions is:**

Are either of these scenarios correct? In addition to the above situation, if we add wind blowing over the top of the box, how does this affect the scenario?

Some basic searching on the web was done but varying answers from secondary sources were found, leaving the debate unsettled.

**Disclaimer:**

This debate is not an attempt to circumvent any necessary protocols of confined space safety nor were any regulations set fourth by OSHA and NIOSH ignored.

Comment: Over a sufficiently long time, diffusion would also play a role.

Comment: Isn't it marginally lighter than air, so it would diffuse around the room/trench.  Oil tanks have an earth berm to contain oil during leaks, but berm collects carbon monoxide.

Comment: Use CFD to model it - soon know.

Comment: Because of the risk of CO poisoning, gasoline engines cannot be used in enclosed spaces. Diesel engines must be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

CO won't cause the machine to stop.  An engine is quite happy ingesting CO levels that would kill us.  The engine will run until all oxygen is used up.  It is CO<sub>2</sub> that has a higher specific gravity than air and will displace the oxygen if no convection occurs.

One supposes that the heated CO<sub>2</sub> exhaust will tend to rise out of the pit.  The engine might run continuously.  I would think that any amount of wind would be sufficient to provide enough oxygen.

Comment: Similarly insects are pretty unimpeded by levels of carbon monoxide that would kill mammals.

Answer (score 1):

Situation 1 is more correct than situation 2 in the short to medium time scale. As time goes to infinity (a sufficiently long time for the actual physical scenario), carbon monoxide (CO) levels will drop due to diffusion out of the enclosed volume in question. The gas will cool off as it mixes with the air and since there is likely a lot more air than CO, the CO gas will cool relatively quickly. Also, as StainlessSteelRat brings up in the comments, the specific gravity of gaseous CO is nearly one (at 25°C and 1 atm) so that will further act against natural convection moving CO out of the enclosed volume.

Comment: I'm a little confused. If the air in the box is in contact with the outside air, what would stop the CO from just continually mixing with the outside air? Assuming the CO disperses evenly throughout the container, and since there is no top barrier, wouldn't it keep moving throughout the air and then out of the box?

Comment: The mixing requires some driving force in the form of temperature and/or concentration gradients. What you describe will happen, but it will be a very small factor compared to other factors in play.